# Wordpress hook to edit the post meta data before displaying a post edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, edit

I'm trying to edit a field in the meta data of a post before it is being displayed on the screen.

I have been looking at the 'load-post.php' hook, but this is called before the post is loaded (if I've understood that correctly), so the post id and meta data are null. 
I've tried other hooks, but I haven't been able to make this work.

The following post meta field needs to be changed before it is displayed on the edit page.

```
$post_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'price', TRUE);
```

Example: Price = 10 in the database, but I want it to be Price = 15 when it is displayed on the post edit page.

Any links, tips and ideas are much appreciated. :)

Edit:

My current solution:

```
add_action('load-post.php','calculate_price');
function calculate_price(){
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    //get price from post by post_id and do stuff
}
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: i made this work by calling another add_meta_boxes hook before the add_meta_boxes hook that displays metaboxes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:** okay I thought you just need to work with ID of post. If you need to change post objects (already loaded from db and ready to be printed), you can use ['the_post'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post) instead. Since you just need to access to post id, I would do something like this:

```
function my_the_post_action( $post ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( is_admin() && $screen->parent_base == 'edit' && get_post_type() == 'product' ) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $price = (int) get_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', true );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', $price + 5 );
    } 
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

This part:

> get_post_type() == 'product'

is not necessary, but you should determine for which kind of post (based on post type, category, metafield etc.) you want to run this piece of code. Without it will be executed everytime in admin query. This code is not tested, if something is wrong feel free to report.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but doesn't this hook allow you to change the query? I don't need to change the query, I need a hook that allows me to change the data from the query result.

Comment: Thank you, looks way better then my solution, but the 'the_post' seems to be ignored. Any ideas? 
the add_action is in a construct function in a class if that matters. I'm pretty new to hooks and wordpress.

Comment: Try to use this snippet outside of class, in theme functions.php. Then if nothing happends, put echo 'works'; at the beginning of my_the_post_action to be really sure nothing happends. In admin area watch source code near body, beacuse 'works' maybe hidden.

Comment: OP is trying to transform the data *for display purposes* rather than permanently update the database, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The best hook I found is [load-post.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)) using `$current_screen`.

For Woocommerce product, that works :

```
add_action('load-post.php', "calculate_price" );

function calculate_price( ){
   global $current_screen;
   if( is_admin() && $current_screen->post_type === 'product' ){
       $post_id = (int) $_GET['post'];
       $post = get_post( $post_id );
       //Do something
   }
}
```